# Getting one row from left join

Tags: mysql

Probably bad title, but I could not find better short description.

These are the tables Im working with:

```
Table Objects:

ID
NAME

Table Geo:

ID
NAME
PARENT_ID (int)
IDENTIFIER (varchar)

Table ObjectsGeo:

ID
OBJECT_ID
GEO_ID
```

So I insert some data in "objects":

```
insert into objects values(1,'Jack');   
insert into objects values(2,'Penny');
```

And then in "geo":

```
insert into geo values(1,'USA', null, '001');   
insert into geo values(2,'New York', 1, '1001');    
insert into geo values(3,'England', null, '002');   
insert into geo values(4,'London', 3, '1002');
```

If Jack lives in New York, then I will insert it this way:

```
insert into ObjectsGeo values(1,1,1);   
insert into ObjectsGeo values(2,1,2);
```

If you tell me this is a bad database design, I will agree (somebody else coded this). However, this is what I have now and making changes in the design could be complicated/cause bugs somewhere else.

Now, when I need to fetch Jack from database, as I also want to know where he lives, I do something quite ugly, which is having a left join to also include "ObjectsGeo". I then only take the first row (sigh) and "manually" put city and country in the object with programming code.
Is there a way, with only one query, to get the row for Jack including 2 fields, one for country and one for city?

----EDIT----
The tables were more or less pseudocode. The query itself (also as pseudocode) should be:

```
select o.*, g.identifier from objects o left join ObjectsGeo og on og.object_id = o.id left join Geo g on g.id = og.geo_id where o.id = 1;
```

Comment: Please share what you have tried so far. I think Left Join will do the trick for you.

Comment: Post what you tried and what you need actual output

Comment: It is not the real tables IM working with I wrote about. So now I guess the query (transformed from the ones Im using) should be:select o.*, g.identifier 
from objects o 
left join ObjectsGeo og on og.object_id = o.id
left join Geo g on g.id = og.geo_id 
where o.id = 1;

Comment: The result is 2 rows. With the same fields all over but the identifier which is different for row 1 and 2.

Comment: And I wonder if it is possible to only get one row with both identifier fields, called each with its own name, something like: geo_country and geo_city

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following query will get the job done:

```
select o.name, 
       (select name from geo where id = min(og.geo_id)) as geo_country, 
       (select name from geo where id = max(og.geo_id)) as geo_city
from objects o
inner join objectsgeo og
on og.object_id = o.id
inner join geo g
on g.id = og.geo_id
group by og.object_id;
```

[Click here for Demo](http://rextester.com/HAUIY45756)

If you've any doubt(s), feel free to ask by commenting below.

Hope it helps!